# Custom attribute - Product page

Tags: php, attributes, xml, product-view, magento2.1.6

I created a custom attribute `dispname` and I would like to add it under the name on the product page. 
I tried to change the xml file `catalog_product_view.xml` but it doesn't work. 
I can add it in the tab "More Information" but not under the name of the product.

[image]

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate pleace check the link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179912/get-product-attribute-in-custom-phtml-block-added-to-product-page-through-xml/179919#179919

Comment: check at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181785/magento-2-attribute-position-change/1

Answer (score 0):

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="specification_tab" template="product/view/attribute.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSpecification</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">specification</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">specification</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Specification</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Please use this code inside `catalog_product_view.xml` file under tag `<referenceContainer name="content">`